# Xamarin.Forms - Open an Android Intent?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am trying to open a PDF in Xamarin.Forms (Android)

How would I translate this Java to C# in the Android project (PCL) and what namespaces are used??

```
Intent intentUrl = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intentUrl.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
intentUrl.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
mActivity.startActivity(intentUrl);
```

I've got this far, but how do I call the actiity in an injected class?

```
        Uri uri = new Uri("file:///" + PathToFile(filename));
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
        intent.SetDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
        intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
        Android.MainActivity. ???????
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your code examples. Are you trying to make a Xamarin.Forms project or are you using Xamarin.Android directly?

Comment: I have a Xamarin.Forms application in PCL for Android.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution

```
using Uri = Android.Net.Uri;

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
        intent.SetDataAndType(Uri.Parse("file:///" + PathToFile(filename)), "application/pdf");
        intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
        Forms.Context.StartActivity(intent);
        return null;
```