# Android: How do I construct *full* path to pass to Intent.CreateChooser

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Trying to make Android chooser to display available actions for user to launch a PDF file which is stored in my local folder. 
When I pass the file name like **/data/user/0/myappappname/files/output.pdf** , (which exsists, of course), I get a nice chooser with all the apps that can accept a pdf file. But when I pick any of them, I get an error (from external app) **The document path is not valid.**  No exception is thrown.

Then I tried (for testing purposes) to set *fname* to something like **/storage/emulated/0/Download/TLCL.pdf** (file also exists), and everything works fine.

At first, I thought that this has something to do with file permissions (since first path is private to my app), but then I found flag *ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission* built exactly for purpose of temporarily granting file access to other apps. Still same results.

Since this is a Xamarin.forms project, I am limited in choice of file creation locations (I use PCLStorage, which always writes to app-private, local folder), so I don't have an option of generating files in /Documents, /Downloads etc.

I am obviously doing something wrong. Any ideas appreciated.

Is there an option to get *full* path from system, including the **/storage/emulated/0** part (or whatever that would be on other devices)? Maybe that would help?

---

**Piece of code:**

(mimeType is defined as "application/pdf" earlier)

```
 public async Task<bool> LaunchFile(string fname, string mimeType)
        {
            var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("file://" + fname );
            var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
            intent.SetDataAndType(uri, mimeType);

            intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearWhenTaskReset | ActivityFlags.NewTask | ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission );

            try
            {
                Forms.Context.StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "ChooseApp"));
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("LaunchFile: " + ex.Message);
                return false;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution to this, which may not be exactly what you want, is to generate a file (in my case a zip file), export it to a public folder, and use that file for the chooser.

Using these:

```
private readonly string PublicDocsPath = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath + "/AppName";
private readonly string PrivateDocsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
```

and some basic functions:

```
    public Stream GetOutputStream(string destFilePath)
    {
        string destFolderPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(destFilePath);
        if (!Directory.Exists(destFolderPath))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(destFolderPath);
        return new FileStream(destFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
    }
    public Stream GetInputStream(string sourceFilePath)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(sourceFilePath)) throw new FileNotFoundException();
        string sourceFolderPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(sourceFilePath);
        return new FileStream(sourceFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
    }
```

You can copy your file to your public folder (or subfolders, you just have to assemble the path) and use that file for your chooser:

```
    public void SendEmail(string subject, string body, string recipient, string mimeType, string attachmentFilePath, string activityTitle)
    {
        var emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionSendMultiple);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(subject)) throw new ArgumentException();
        emailIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraSubject, subject);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(recipient))
            emailIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraEmail, new[] { recipient });
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(body))
            emailIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraText, body);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(attachmentFilePath))
        {
            var file = new Java.IO.File(attachmentFilePath);
            file.SetReadable(true, true);
            var uri = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(file);
            emailIntent.PutParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, new List<IParcelable>(){uri});                              
        }
        emailIntent.SetType(mimeType);
        _activity.StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(emailIntent, activityTitle));
    }
```

This chooser specifically lets the user send their file via email or google drive , but you can assemble it however you want. The attachmentFilePath of this function is the same as the string passed into the GetOutputStream function above.

Comment: Hey, that looks like a nice workaround. I will try it out first thing tomorrow. Thanks for taking time and effort.  I will wait for some time to see if someone can solve my original problem (without exporting to public folder), and if not - this is what I'll be doing.

Answer (score 0):

we're using Acr.IO rather than PCLStorage and I recall that has a property that'll return the fullpath for you.
The code we're using is below, but I wonder if you're simply missing "file://" off the start of your path, as I noticed thats in our code, as well as this previous stackoverflow answer to a similar question as this one, [open a PDF in Xamarin.Forms (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27193557/xamarin-forms-open-an-android-intent)
We're using a dependency FileService on Android and using this code to open PDFs:

```
 public void OpenNatively(string filePath) {
        Android.Net.Uri uri;
        if (filePath.StartsWithHTTP()) {
            uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(filePath);
        }
        else {
             uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("file:///" + filePath);
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
        var extension = filePath.Substring(filePath.LastIndexOf(".")+1);
        if (extension == "ppt" || extension == "pptx") {
            extension = "vnd.ms-powerpoint";
        }
        var docType = "application/" + extension;
        intent.SetDataAndType(uri, docType);
        intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearWhenTaskReset | ActivityFlags.NewTask);

        try {
            Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context.StartActivity(intent);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.MakeText(Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context, "No Application found to view " + extension.ToUpperInvariant() + " files.", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. That is basically same as I was doing. The problem is definitely in access rights for the file created in app private folder.  Acr.IO seems nice at first glance though, thank you for that info.